# Python: All type hints errors in subclass constructure seems ignored

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following code with python type hints
It has a bunch of errors. All erros in code are found by mypy but not the errors in constructor of S. Why? I cannot find out what is happening
thanks

code:

```
import typing

class T(object):
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: str = None) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b: typing.Union[str, None] = b
        self._callback_map: typing.Dict[str, str] = {}


class S(T):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self, 1, 2)
        self._callback_map[1] = "TOTO"
        s = T(1, 1)
        t = T(1, b=2)
        t._callback_map[2] = "jj"


s = T(1, 2)

t = T(1, b=2)
t._callback_map[2] = "jj"
```

output of mypy:

```
 t.py:22: error: Argument 2 to "T" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[str]"
t.py:24: error: Argument "b" to "T" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Optional[str]"
rt.py:25: error: Invalid index type "int" for "Dict[str, str]"; expected type "str"
```

This is fine, but the same errors (same lines) in '**init**' at line 16, 17, 18 are not found at all...

Comment: I believe `b` in `class T(object)` is of `type str` and you are passing an int form the `class S(T)` why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mypy, by default, will only check functions and methods that have type annotations.

Your subclass's constructor has no annotations and so consequently goes unchecked.

To fix this, modify the signature to read `def __init__(self) -> None`.

You can also ask mypy to flag these errors for you using the `--disallow-untyped-defs` flag. You can also use the `--check-untyped-defs` flag which will make it typecheck all functions, whether or not it has annotations.

Comment: completely correct. Thanks. That was a rather un-intuitive default

Comment: @OlivierRD: the rationale here is that PEP 484 wants to treat regular, untyped code as being fully dynamic. This is a nice property because it means that regular, untyped Python code is automatically PEP 484 compliant: you don't have a divide in semantics between "regular" Python code and "typed" Python code. This feature also makes it possible for people to add type hints into existing large codebases and fix errors progressively, rather then all at once.