# Python Type Hints ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-typing

I'm new to python and experimenting with type hints, however they only seem to work in some instances. They seem to work as expected on the property return type, however when I try to assign an integer to a string value (i.e. self._my_string = 4), I get no issues reported.

```
class TypeHintTest(object):
    _my_string: str

    def __init__(self):
        self._my_string = 4  # no error

    @property
    def as_int(self) -> int:  
        return self._my_string  # Error : expected int got str
```

The resulting object then contains an int value (as expected).

I'm using pyCharm 2018.3.2 Community edition, the interpreter is 3.6

[image]

The following question seems to be similar, but the solution of changing the constructor to `def __init__(self) -> None` does not change anything.
[Python: All type hints errors in subclass constructure seems ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509163/python-all-type-hints-errors-in-subclass-constructure-seems-ignored)

Comment: This is an issue with the PyCharm type checker, not python. Raise a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FPY). Similarly - pycharm doesn't report `x: str = 4` as an error. The link you posted is about mypy, another type checker unrelated to pycharm.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FHTMitchell points out its a bug in PyCharm

see [Bug tracker entry](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33376)

Answer (score 3):

Type hints are, as the name suggests, hints. Python does not raise an error if you assign a different type to a variable.
Pycharm, however, *should* say that it expected another variable type.

Comment: is it the same as adding a comment ? kind of useless if it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SonicSoul Python is a language with dynamic typing, so, type hints can't be used in runtime by default, but type hints is not the same as free-format comments - they can be used by separate tools for static analysis (like mypy) and IDE (like PyCharm).