# Raise an error if type hint is violated/ignored in Python?

Tags: python, runtime, type-hinting

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020807/python-type-hints-ignored) I learned that the type hints are, by default, not enforced whilst executing Python code.

One can detect *some* discrepancies between the type hints and actual argument types using a slightly convoluted process of running `pyannotate` to generate stubs whilst running Python code, and scanning for differences after applying these stubs to the code.

However, it would be more convenient/faster to directly raise an exception if an incoming argument is not of the type included in the type hint. This can be achieved by manually including:

```py
if not isinstance(some_argument, the_type_hint_type):
    raise TypeError("Argument:{argument} is not of type:{the_type_hint_type}")
```

However, that is quite labour intensive. Hence, I was curious, is it possible to make Python raise an error if a type-hint is violated, using an CLI argument or pip package or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps you - https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-the-decorator

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

The edit queue for the Answer by @Surya_1897 is full, hence I will include a more detailed description of the solution here.

[Typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard) does exactly what I was looking for. The following requirements apply:

1. Install typeguard with:

```
pip install typeguard
```

2. Import typeguard into each script, and add the `@typechecked` property above **each** function.
3. Example:
   Change:

```py
"""Some file description."""

def add_two(x:int):
    """Adds two to an incoming int."""
    return x+2
somevar:float=42.1
add_two(somevar)
```

To:

```py
"""Some file description."""
from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def add_two(x:int):
    """Adds two to an incoming int."""
    return x+2
somevar:float=42.1
add_two(somevar)
```

The latter will than throw an err:

> TypeError: type of argument "x" must be int; got float instead